# MSBUILD + LOCAL FOLDER DEPLOY

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, iis-express, virtual-directory

I Have an ASPX project, to which I created a LocalFolderRelease publish profile, which is a FileSystem typed publish. I want to make a deploy package using the MSBUILD.EXE on a specific (Team City) client machine with the following option:

```
msbuild.exe MyAspxProject.csproj /p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;PackageAsSingleFile=False;PublishProfile=LocalFolderRelease
```

This drops an error:

```
MyAspxProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\web.config(73): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. [MyAspxProject.csproj]
```

I don't really understand what does it mean anyway, also cannot understand why it verifies this in the IIS as I don't want to install this deploy package on *this* machine :(

What I do want is to disable the IIS check step during generating this deploy package.

There is no other web.config in my application, the only one is in the root of the application source folder!

Comment: The speicifed line in the web.config holds the following line: <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem it was. It happens that the web.config was set to "copy always", which means that it generated into the root folder, and also copied into the bin/ folder. The most interesting is that in a simple "web deploy" using "file system", copying the files directly to the server's inetpub\subfolder\ causes no problem before. When the target folder name changed from \server\c$\inetpub\subfolder to c:\subfolder it gives this "fake" error.